# Magento 2 callback dimensionsChanged accordion does not work

Tags: magento2, javascript, callback, accordion

I built an accordion from the Magento 2 documentation.

**CODE JS:**

```
$(".init-accordion").accordion({
    "active": [1, 2],
    "collapsible": true,
    "openedState": "active",
    "multipleCollapsible": true,
    dimensionsChanged: function(event, data) {
        var opened = data.opened;

        if (opened) {
            // do something when the content is opened
            return;
        }
        // do something when the content is closed
    }
});
```

The accordion works but the `dimensionsChanged` callback does not work.

[Magento 2 documentation accordion](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html)

Does anyone know why and how can I make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
use below code.. it might works for you.

$(".init-accordion").accordion({
    "active": [1, 2],
    "collapsible": true,
    "openedState": "active",
    "multipleCollapsible": true,
}); 
$(".init-accordion").on("dimensionsChanged", function (event, data) {
    var opened = data.opened;

    if (opened) {
        // do something when the content is opened
        return;
    }
    // do something when the content is closed
});
```

Comment: I tried it before posting and it still doesn't work, is it a Magento bug?